# In R, how do I create individual time series (to loop trough and run a Mann-Kendall test) from a larger dataset?

Tags: r, loops, time-series, trend

I am starting to automate our Mann-Kendall tests used for time series data of water quality data. It was done in Excel before, but was too much copying and pasting. I want to create an R script to run the MK test (package ‘trend’) and calculate the Sens Slope. I have the following example table with our water quality data:

```
| Site | Program | Year | parameter1 | parameter2 |
|------|---------|------|-----|-----|
| A    | ABC     | 1990 | 5   | 100 |
| A    | ABC     | 1991 | 10  | 75  |
| A    | ABC     | 1992 | 15  | 50  |
| A    | ABC     | 1993 | 20  | 25  |
| A    | ABC     | 1994 | 25  | 5   |
| B    | ABC     | 1990 | 10  | 88  |
| B    | ABC     | 1991 | 20  | 44  |
| B    | ABC     | 1992 | 30  | 22  |
| B    | ABC     | 1993 | 40  | 11  |
| B    | ABC     | 1994 | 50  | 6   |
| C    | XYZ     | 1990 | 6   | 64  |
| C    | XYZ     | 1991 | 12  | 44  |
| C    | XYZ     | 1992 | 18  | 24  |
| C    | XYZ     | 1993 | 24  | 14  |
| C    | XYZ     | 1994 | 30  | 4   |
| D    | XYZ     | 1990 | 7   | 99  |
| D    | XYZ     | 1991 | 14  | 88  |
| D    | XYZ     | 1992 | 21  | 77  |
| D    | XYZ     | 1993 | 28  | 66  |
| D    | XYZ     | 1994 | 35  | 55  |
```

I need to take out each time series in the data (so for sites A,B,C,D) for each parameter (ANC and SO4) and run the MannKendall test in R (code below). I need an output table to look like the following, but with the MK statistic and sens slope filled in (not 1 like it shows below).

```
| Site | Program | Parameter | MK Statistic | Sens Slope |
|------|---------|-----------|--------------|------------|
| A    | ABC     | ANC       | 1            | 1          |
| A    | ABC     | SO4       | 1            | 1          |
| B    | ABC     | ANC       | 1            | 1          |
| B    | ABC     | SO4       | 1            | 1          |
| C    | XYZ     | ANC       | 1            | 1          |
| C    | XYZ     | SO4       | 1            | 1          |
| D    | XYZ     | ANC       | 1            | 1          |
| D    | XYZ     | SO4       | 1            | 1          |
```

Any idea on how to produce this output table? I know it will require a loop at some point, but not entirely sure where to start. Perhaps a for each site, program, and then either ANC or S04. The R code below is from an individual site and parameter combo, but this would be a pain to have to replicate for the 100’s of sites and 6 water quality parameters we have.

```
install.packages("trend")
library("trend")

#put our data in a time series (but this only creates 1 site and its time series)
time_series <- ts(Trends$parameter1, start=c(1990, 1), end=c(1994, 1), frequency=1)
print(time_series)


#Run the MK Test and Sens Slope from package trend
mk.test(time_series, alternative = c("two.sided", "greater", "less"),
continuity = TRUE)
sens.slope(time_series, conf.level = 0.95)
```

Output Example - these are results from my actual data, not the example dataset (since I haven't succesfully run the MKtest on all sites in the example data). Numbers with the ^^^^ below them are the numbers I need for the final output table.

```
> mk.test(time_series , alternative = c("two.sided", "greater", "less"),
+ continuity = TRUE)

    Mann-Kendall trend test

data:  time_series
z = -5.7308, n = 26, p-value = 9.996e-09
alternative hypothesis: true S is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
           S         varS          tau 
-261.0000000 2058.3333333   -0.8030769 
^^^^^^^^^^^^

> sens.slope(time_series , conf.level = 0.95)

    Sens slope

data:  time_series
z = -5.7308, n = 26, p-value = 9.996e-09
alternative hypothesis: true z is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.3187075 -0.9495238
sample estimates:
Sens slope
  -1.136842
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you check my updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a different approach that uses the tidyverse. It might be a bit outside your experience so far but I recommend checking it out as I find it is easier to use than base R when you are coming from excel

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

install.packages("trend")
library("trend")  

out <- dat %>% gather(parameter, value, ANC, SO4) %>% 
  group_by(parameter, Site) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(ts_out = map(data, ~ts(.x$value, start=c(1990, 1), end=c(1994, 1), frequency=1))) %>% 
  mutate(mk_res = map(ts_out, ~mk.test(.x, alternative = c("two.sided", "greater", "less"),
                                      continuity = TRUE)),
         sens = map(ts_out, ~sens.slope(.x, conf.level = 0.95))) %>% 
  mutate(mk_stat = map_dbl(mk_res, ~.x$p.value),
         sens_stat = map_dbl(sens, ~.x$p.value)) %>% 
  select(parameter, Site, mk_stat, sens_stat)

out
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  parameter Site     mk_stat sens_stat
  <chr>     <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 ANC       " A    "  0.0275    0.0275
2 ANC       " B    "  0.0275    0.0275
3 ANC       " C    "  0.0275    0.0275
4 ANC       " D    "  0.0275    0.0275
5 SO4       " A    "  0.0275    0.0275
6 SO4       " B    "  0.0275    0.0275
7 SO4       " C    "  0.0275    0.0275
8 SO4       " D    "  0.0275    0.0275
```

This gives the output in a table. I am not sure if that is the part you want to pull out from the tests but that should be easier to change

I recommend looking at the output at each step to get an idea of the structure. A good resource for this style of analysis is [R for Data Science Many Models Chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)

Comment: Stepped away from this project for a bit, but now back at it. Do you know if this pipeline could handle removing time-series data with missing values? My real data has quite a few missing values. I'm ok not having a result for some sites.

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you add some missing data to your example and let us know?

Answer (score 2):

We can `split` the dataset by 'Site' into a `list` of `data.frames` and apply the test

```
library(trend)
lst1 <- split(Trends[c("parameter1", "parameter2")], Trends$Site)
out <- lapply(lst1, function(dat) 
           lapply(dat, function(para) {                

           time_series <- ts(para, start=c(1983, 1), end=c(2018, 1), frequency=1)
           tsout <- mk.test(time_series, alternative = c("two.sided", 
                   "greater", "less"), continuity = TRUE)
           sensout <- sens.slope(time_series, conf.level = 0.95) 
   list(tsout = tsout, sensout = sensout)
  }
  ))
```

-output

```
out$A$parameter1
#$tsout

#   Mann-Kendall trend test

#data:  time_series
#z = 0.57147, n = 36, p-value = 0.5677
#alternative hypothesis: true S is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#           S         varS          tau 
#4.200000e+01 5.147333e+03 7.352146e-02 


#$sensout

#   Sen's slope

#data:  time_series
#z = 0.57147, n = 36, p-value = 0.5677
#alternative hypothesis: true z is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.0000 0.3125
#sample estimates:
#Sen's slope 
#          0 

out$D$parameter2
#$tsout

#   Mann-Kendall trend test

#data:  time_series
#z = -0.57147, n = 36, p-value = 0.5677
#alternative hypothesis: true S is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#            S          varS           tau 
# -42.00000000 5147.33333333   -0.07352146 


#$sensout

#   Sen's slope

#data:  time_series
#z = -0.57147, n = 36, p-value = 0.5677
#alternative hypothesis: true z is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -0.6875  0.0000
#sample estimates:
#Sen's slope 
#          0
```

#### data

```
Trends <- structure(list(Site = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
    Program = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
    "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", 
    "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ"), Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
    1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 
    1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L), 
    parameter1 = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
    50L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 30L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 35L), parameter2 = c(100L, 
    75L, 50L, 25L, 5L, 88L, 44L, 22L, 11L, 6L, 64L, 44L, 24L, 
    14L, 4L, 99L, 88L, 77L, 66L, 55L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I will have to manually enter in the ANC and S04 each time.  Is there a way to loop this? Also, is there a way to get the results into a table? The MK statistic and sens slope seem to be hidden in a list. I only need the MKstatistic and sens slope and p value.

Comment: @ScottR. What is `ANC` and `S04` in your code.  Sorry, I didn't see that

Comment: Those are the specific parameters. Think of them as parameter1 and parameter2 if that makes more sense. There will be 6 parameters in our final dataset. I should have noted that better.

Comment: @ScottR. Can you please update your post with how you are passing it